# nltk NER word extraction

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I have checked previous related threads, but did not solve my issue. I have written code to get NER from text.

```
text = "Stallone jason's film Rocky was inducted into the National Film Registry as well as having its film props placed in the Smithsonian Museum."

tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary = True)
print namedEnt
namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary = False)
```

which gives this short of result

```
(S
  (NE Stallone/NNP)
  jason/NN
  's/POS
  film/NN
  (NE Rocky/NNP)
  was/VBD
  inducted/VBN
  into/IN
  the/DT
  (NE National/NNP Film/NNP Registry/NNP)
  as/IN
  well/RB
  as/IN
  having/VBG
  its/PRP$
  film/NN
  props/NNS
  placed/VBN
  in/IN
  the/DT
  (NE Smithsonian/NNP Museum/NNP)
  ./.)
```

while I expect only NE as a result, like

```
Stallone
Rockey
National Film Registry
Smithsonian Museum
```

how to achieve this?

**UPDATE**

```
result = ' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.node == "NE"
print result
```

gives syntext error, what is correct way to write this?

**UPDATE2**

text = "Stallone jason's film Rocky was inducted into the National Film Registry as well as having its film props placed in the Smithsonian Museum."

```
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary = True)
print namedEnt
np = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.node == "NE"]
print np
```

error:

```
 np = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.node == "NE"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tree.py", line 198, in _get_node
    raise NotImplementedError("Use label() to access a node label.")
NotImplementedError: Use label() to access a node label.
```

so I tried with

```
np = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.label() == "NE"]
```

which gives emtpy result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `namedEnt` returned is actually a `Tree` object which is a subclass of `list`. You can do the following to parse it:

```
[' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.node == "NE"]
```

Output:

```
['Stallone', 'Rocky', 'National Film Registry', 'Smithsonian Museum']
```

The `binary` flag is set to `True` will indicate only whether a subtree is NE or not, which is what we need above. When set to `False` it will give more information like whether the NE is an Organization, Person etc. For some reason, the result with flag On and Off don't seem to agree with one another.

Comment: thanks a lot, but how to use this? I updated the question, still get error with this

Comment: Its a list comprehension, so you will have to embed it in '[ ]' like `result = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.node == "NE"]`

Comment: Also, use this with `binary=True`

Comment: thanks but still there is issue, please see update2 in question

Comment: can you tell me the nltk version number. do `import nltk; nltk.__version__` in the interpreter to get this.

Comment: Yes. I had a old version. In the new version of nltk there is no `node()` function. But your line `np = [' '.join([y[0] for y in x.leaves()]) for x in namedEnt.subtrees() if x.label() == "NE"]` works for me after updating my nltk. Try to debug further like seeing what is in namedEnt

Comment: Thanks for this answer , but  how to add names in ner ?